# Could you help me : compactness of a set from compact product

Tags: compactness

If S is compact and S= $A\times B$ product of two spaces. Is that enough to state that continuous image of a compact space is compact to state A is compact if we define $f: S\rightarrow$ A is continuous ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: That statament is true only in metric spaces. In metric space compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent things.

Comment: I mean if  A×B is compact in M×N. How could I prove that A and B are compact too.

Comment: The projection $A\times B\to A$ is continuous, and the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: for the contiunity can we say (a,b) → (a) then f(a,b) →f(a) ? or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every sequence $(a_n, b_n)$ in  $A \times B$ has a convergent subsequence, then, by definition any sequence in $A$ ( or $B$) has a convergent subsequence. If not, we could "lift" a sequence without a convergent subsequence into the product $ A \times B$, to get a non-convergent subsequence.  EDIT: This follows from what I think is the standard definition of convergence of a sequence in a product space: we say $(a_n,b_n ) \rightarrow (a,b)$ iff $a_n \rightarrow a $ and $b_n \rightarrow b$

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the downvote. My crystall ball is in the shop and my psychic is vacationing in the islands, so I will not be able to guess what is on your mind anytime soon.